# How can I put an image in-front others in HTML/CSS when z-index isn't working?

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I'm currently working on a module in HTML/CSS and JS.

In my code I have 4 images in `absolute` position. I would like `1 of them` to move (with animations) `in front` of `the others`.

My HTML code looks like that :

```
<section class="bar-container">

      <img id="oyster">

      <img class="waves" id="wave-1">
      <img class="waves" id="wave-2">
      <img class="waves" id="wave-3">    
        
      <div class="progression-bar">
             some stuff
      </div>
</section>
```

And my CSS code looks like this :

```
.bar-container {
    position: relative;
}

.bar-container #oyster {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8.5%;
    top: 38%;
    animation: 2s ease infinite slideup;
    transition: left 1.5s;
    z-index: 4;
}

.bar-container #wave-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 14%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
}

.bar-container #wave-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 39%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}

.bar-container #wave-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 64%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The fact is that my `oyster` is behind the waves and I tried a lot of different combinaisons but it still not working as i would like to...

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRtGr.png)

I really don't know how to do what I would like... Can someone help me ?

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet so we can see the problem and include the animation.

Comment: I have tried the code you have given and the oyster img is in front of the other imgs.Please show the animation as that would seem to be the only way the oyster position could alter.

Comment: @AHaworth the animation is a basic change of the 'left' position ins JS.

Looking like this : 
oyster.style.left = "33.5%";

But the oyster also have an animation which makes it sliding up and down all time.
Looking like this :
```
oyster {
       animation: 2s ease infinite slideup;
}

@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(15%)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The oyster is still in front for me. I think you need to put up a working snippet into your question that we can run and that shows the problem. You do need to be aware that certain things (e.g. transforms, opacity) can create new stacking contexts, but I haven't so far found that problem here